# How to Jquery Slider in web part Kentico

Tags: content-management-system, kentico

Can any one have idea for the perfect choice for making kentico CMS web part hold slider content ?
I've tried to to use (repeater), but it's not complete and doesn't match requirement

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at Kentico's built-in Content slider webpart? Its example is placed on Corporate site samples site - /Examples/Web-parts/Listings-and-viewers/Documents/Content-slider.aspx.

Comment: yes i have seen it but even using slider web part also didn't match my requirement because (Image Slider Webpart for Kentico CMS V 6) it look like template and i want the repeater to do this mission

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use flexslider 2 (http://flexslider.woothemes.com/) and use custom document types and repeaters to accomplish content sliders in Kentico CMS.

In the repeater web part, we use the HTML Envelope to put the container elements in, then use the transformation to repeat through the dynamic section.

We put this in the Content before:

```
<div class="flexslider"><br/>
<ul class="slides">
```

and we put the closing tags in the Content after:

```
</ul><br/>
</div>
```

Then the transformation contains this:

```
<li><br/>
  <img src="slide1.jpg" /><br/>
</li>
```

Add the JavaScript file references to your page, specify the path to your slider documents in the repeater web part and it should work like you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the custom document type, what did you use for it?

Also you mention to add the script files to the page, did you add the script files in template?